# Django save a series of question and its corresponding answer set to database

Tags: javascript, python, django, django-models, django-views

I am a newbie in Django and I am working on a quiz functionality.
I give the user an interface to create a quiz. It is based on a multi-step form. I input a certain number of questions and hit next. It displays that amount of fields for me to set the questions. Each question has 4 answers and I use radio buttons to select the right answer. The problem is I don't know how to retrieve them in my views when I hit the submit button. Like I want each question and its corresponding answers to be properly stored in the respective models. Can you guys please? It's lengthy but easy to grasp and some details can be overlooked as they are just fields :)

Here is my code:

models.py

```
class PsychometricTest(models.Model):
     DIFF_CHOICES = (
         ('easy', 'easy'),
         ('medium', 'medium'),
         ('hard', 'hard'),
     )
     internship = models.ForeignKey(Internship, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
     name = models.CharField(max_length=120)
     description = models.TextField()
     number_of_questions = models.IntegerField()
     time = models.IntegerField(help_text="Duration of the quiz in minutes")
     required_score_to_pass = models.IntegerField(help_text="required score in %")
     difficulty = models.CharField(max_length=6, choices=DIFF_CHOICES)
     created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
     scheduled_date_time = models.DateTimeField()

     def __str__(self):
         return self.name+" - "+self.topic
 
    def get_questions(self):
         return self.question_set.all()

 class Question(models.Model):
     text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
     psychometric_test = models.ForeignKey(PsychometricTest, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
     created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

     def __str__(self):
          return self.text
 
     def get_answers(self):
         return self.answer_set.all()

 class Answer(models.Model):
    test = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    correct = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return "Question: "+self.question.text+", answer: "+self.text+", correct: "+self.correct

 class Result(models.Model):
     psychometric_test = models.ForeignKey(PsychometricTest, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
     student = models.ForeignKey(StudentUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
     score = models.FloatField()
 
     def __str__(self):
        return self.student.user.username+": "+self.psychometric_test+", score="+self.score
```

add_test.html

```
    <form style="margin-top: 20px;" action="{% url 'add_test' internship.id  %}" 
     id="add_test_form" method="POST" >
        <!--This form will contain the quiz information-->
        {% csrf_token %}
        <div class="step_div first" style="display: none;">

        <label>Number of questions</label>
                        <input type="number" class="form-control" name="test_num_questions" 
        id="num_qu" min="1" oninput="validity.valid||(value='')"  >

     <script>
       $('#num_qu').on('change', function(){
       var num_of_qu = $('#num_qu').val();
       var html = "";

       for (var i = 1; i <= num_of_qu; i++) {
           html += `<div class="row"><div class="form-row"><div class="form-group col-md-6">
           <label>Name of question</label><input type="text" class="form-control" 
           name="question_text" placeholder="Question"></div></div></div>`;
        
            for (j = 1; j < 5; j++) {
            //4 answers
               html += `<div class="row">
               <div class="form-row">
               <div class="form-group col-md-4">
               <input type="text" class="form-control" name="answers_${j}" id="answer_${j}"
               placeholder="Answer"><input
               type="radio"
               name="answer_for_qu${i}"
               id="answer_${j}">
               </div>
               </div>
               </div>`
       
    }
}
    
    $(".step_div.second").html(html);
  });
```

views.py

```
def add_test(request, pid):
    if not request.user.is_authenticated:
        messages.warning(request, "Please login first")
        return redirect('login')

    if request.method == 'POST':
        test_name = request.POST['test_name']
        test_description = request.POST['test_desc']
        test_num_questions = request.POST['test_num_questions']
        test_duration = request.POST['test_duration']
        test_threshold = request.POST['test_threshold']
        test_diff_level = request.POST['test_diff_level']
        test_datetime = request.POST['test_datetime']

    # print(test_name)
    # print(test_description)
    # print(test_num_questions)
    # print(test_duration)
    # print(test_threshold)
    # print(test_diff_level)
    # print(test_datetime)
    
 internship = Internship.objects.get(id=pid)
 context = {
    'internship': internship,
  }
  return render(request, 'add_test.html', context)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Second edit:

```
class SetData(APIView):
    def post(self, request):
        q_num = request.GET.get('q_num', False)
        for i in range(int(q_num)):
            question=Question(text=request.POST['question_text_{}'.format(i)])
            question.save()

            for j in range(4)
                Answer(
                text=request.POST['answers_{}_{}].format(i, j),
                        question=question,
                ...).save()
```

this is how you pass question total number via your request:

```
<form action="{% url 'add_test' internship.id  %}?p_num=set this with js" method="POST" >
```

to set q_num with js, you need to select your "form element" and edit it's action. something like:

```
<form action="{% url 'add_test' internship.id  %}" method="POST" >

...

document.getElementById("add_test_form").action += '?q_num=' + num_of_qu;
```

you  won't need to change your url.

---

First edit:

I can't help you with javascript but here's how you get data from a post requst in django:
(This is a class based view, not much different from function based.)

```
class SetData(APIView):
    def post(self, request):
        test_num_questions = 
        request.POST['test_num_questions']
        # or if for example you wanna check if a submit input
        # (name='mysubmit') is clicked (in this case, you're
        # not sure if request.POST['test_num_questions']
        # returns True or error:
        
        mysubmit = 
        request.POST.get('mysubmit', False)
        # returns False if it there's no
        # request.POST['mysubmit']
```

Btw, why don't you use [django forms](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Django/Forms) or even better, [django model forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/forms/modelforms/#modelform)?

Comment: this i know. The issue is how to retrieve all the question and its answers. For example question 1 and its 4 answers, question 2 and its 4 answers, ...

Comment: Im not comfortable with django forms :((

Comment: Trust me, they're amazing! Serializers are even better, 
 since you don't have to deal with front end! `=) just write what you can figure out about your view and we can start from there.

Comment: I heard that from so many peeps. Still can't get used :/ Ok I'll post my view

Comment: added the view part

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm understanding you're question right. You wanna know how to store your data in database, or gather all questions and answers before saving them to database?

Comment: I want to retrieve the question and its corresponding answers for all the question numbers and store them accordingly in db

Comment: Ok so, why don't you use i (qhestion counter) in the question and answer input name, too? This way you first save the quetuon in 'question_text_1' and then save it's pk as foreign key for answer objects created from 'answers_${j}_1' input.  View code will be sth like how you created the inputs in the first place by js but now you should find them in request.POST.

Comment: hmmm. Bit confused :/

Comment: I'll edit my answer soon. Note that in this solution you need to pass total number of questions to your view via request link. There are another ways, too, of course.

Comment: when you say q_num set this with js, how does it become?

Comment: it says Internship matching query does not exist.

Comment: I am not able to do it

Comment: i added "setting q_num with js" in my answer. "Internship matching query does not exist." means the pid you have passed as argument in "internship = Internship.objects.get(id=pid)" doesn't exist in database.

Comment: how does it become in code? The internship exists btw

Comment: I wrote the java script code. add "document..." line after definition of q_num in script tag (in html file). about internship, you should check the value in pid then. add "print('pid:' + str(pid))" to beginning of view and the result will be printed in manager console. how exactly are you running your project? if you're using pycharm, check your manage.py console tab at the bottom and find the print results in viewes will be shown there. if the value of your pid is correct check print(type(pid)), it must be int.

Comment: ,I am using VSCODE. I am trying to debug

Comment: Isn't it better to search the bug in google? getting hang of bug searching is gonna take some time since you're rather new to django, but you can get your answer much faster than asking them in stack overflow.

Comment: i dont find the answer